# In Google Analytics, what is the differences between a two letter visitor language and the same code duplicated with a dash?

Tags: google-analytics, language, visitors

Wondering about my google analytics visitor languages.
It shows **de** and **de-de**.

Is there any difference between them, if yes what do they mean?
Is there a possability to get them all together in one language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't know how to merge them into Google Analytics, but I can answer the first question.

`de` or `de_de` are (obsiously) the same. They are [*Language tags*](http://www.langtag.net/whatare.html).

- `de` is a *Language subtag*
- `de-de` is a *Region subtag*.

A few examples of language tags:

- `fr`: French language,
- `en-AU`: English language, as written and spoken in Australia,
- `az-Latn-IR`, Azeri language, written in the Latin script, as used in Iran.

So, basically:

- `de` is for German language
- `de-de` is for Germain language as written and spoken in Germany.

This could sound weird, but there is also `fr` & `fr-fr` for example.

Comment: So it would be more locical to have only the language with the region sub tag. Like de-de (germany) de-CH (swiss) and so on...

Comment: More logical, yes. But I guess GA use a custom way to retrieve this information (maybe from the user browser) and that's why you have different language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find the exact match, but [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there are differences between the German language spoken in various areas. Such as German Standard vs German Austria.

It doesn't answer your question completely but hopefully it brings you a little closer to the truth.